# Rotate Object Smoothly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

i am trying to rotate object to 90 degrees smoothly on swipe here in my code its rotate instantly, how do i rotate object smoothly at given speed.

```
void Update()
     {
         if (fingerDown == false && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
         {
             startPos = Input.mousePosition;
             fingerDown = true;
         }
 
         if (fingerDown)
         {
             if (Input.mousePosition.x >= startPos.x + pixelDistToMove)
             {
                 startPos = Input.mousePosition;
                 Vector3 rotationToAdd = new Vector3(0, 0, 90);
                 transform.Rotate(rotationToAdd);
                 fingerDown = false;
             }
 
             if (Input.mousePosition.x <= startPos.x - pixelDistToMove)
             {
                 startPos = Input.mousePosition;
                 Vector3 rotationToAdd = new Vector3(0, 0, -90);
                 transform.Rotate(rotationToAdd);
                 fingerDown = false;
             }
 
         }
 
         if (fingerDown && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
         {
             fingerDown = false;
         }
     }
```

Thank you

Comment: Look for Quaternion.Lerp or Quaternion.Slerp

Comment: how do i implement Quaternion.Slerp. i tried like this it didnt work  ** Quaternion RotateAngle = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, transform.eulerAngles.z + 90);                                           
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, RotateAngle, Time.deltaTime);**

Comment: @OneManMonkeySquad

Answer (score 0):

transform.Rotate() rotates the object without animating it's rotation.
If you want it to rotate smoothly, you have to implement either an animation, or a turning state, or an IEnumerator.

My C# is a bit rusty, but I cooked this up:

```
    public Vector3 desired_angle = Vector3.zero; // Turn the Gameobject to this angle
    public float turn_time = 1f; // How long should turning take
    public float rate = 60;
    private void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) 
        {
            StartCoroutine(TurnTo());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator TurnTo () 
    {
        Vector3 original_angle = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
        for (float i = 0f; i < 1f + turn_time / rate; i += turn_time / rate) 
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.Lerp(original_angle, desired_angle, i));
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(turn_time/rate);

        }
    }
```

Comment: how do i implement IEnumerator here in my code? Thank you.@BCT

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: Thank you very much, its rotating smoothly but its rotating only once, i want to rotate 90 degrees every time i press space button. @BCT

Comment: Change desired angle every time you press space;
`desired_angle += new Vector3(0f, 90f, 0f);`